# Bokeh fails to plot chord diagram when source and target categories are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, chord-diagram

I've just started using Bokeh, specifically because it can (or, at least, I thought it could) plot chord diagrams in a Python environment. However, it seems that the plot fails if the source and target categories are the same. As an example, I've taken the 'hair preference' data that is used for illustration purposes in various other software and tried to plot that data with bokeh. However, the plot fails because there are some instances where source and target are the same. The code is shown below:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""has,prefers,count
"black","red",2868
"blonde","brown",2060
"brown","blonde",16145
"red","black",1013
"black","brown",8916
"blonde","blonde",10048
"brown","black",8010
"red","red",6907
"black","blonde",5871
"blonde","black",1951
"brown","red",8045
"red","brown",940
"black","black",11975
"blonde","red",6171
"brown","brown",8090
"red","blonde",990
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")

chord_from_df = Chord(df, source="has", target="prefers", value="count")
output_file('chord_from_df.html', mode="inline")
show(chord_from_df)
```

But it fails with error:

```
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Does anyone know of a workaround using Bokeh or an alternative Python package that can deal with this situation?

Comment: .@user1718097 any luck on this one? For me, the plot is useless without self-referencing

Comment: @B Furtado: I ended up using circos online - not ideal but it produced a plot that was useful for my purposes.